# How to find the employee that worked the most trips?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update by 5% the salary of the employee who has made the most trips from the start of the current year to this day. There are 2 types of employees: Driver and Hostess. Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employe(  
  nb_emp VARCHAR2(5),  
  salary NUMBER
);
```

`nb_emp` is primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE Trip(  
  id_trip NUMBER,  
  driver VARCHAR2(5),  
  hostess VARCHAR(5),  
  date_trip DATE
);
```

`id_trip` is primary key, driver and `hostess` reference `nb_emp` from table `Employee`.

And here is my query for the driver:

```
update employe
set salary = salary*0.05 + salary
where nb_emp in (
    select driver 
    from trip t
    where 
        nb_emp = t.driver
        and t.date_trip >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR')
        AND t.date_trip < SYSDATE
        and t.id_trip in (
            Select count(tt.id_trip) from trip tt having count(tt.id_trip) = (
                Select Max(s) FROM (select count(ttt.id_trip) as s FROM trip ttt
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The query columns don't match the described tables.

Comment: `e.salary+e.salary*0.5` = `e.salary * 1.5`

Comment: Sorry guys I fell victim for the copy and paste. Edited it all now.

Comment: No you haven't. What does "since this year" mean, do you mean current year? E.g from January 1st this year to current date?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, since this year to this day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to finds workers which made most trips:

```
select emp 
  from (
    select emp, count(1) cnt, max(count(1)) over () mcnt
      from (
        select driver as emp from trip where date_trip between trunc(sysdate, 'year') and sysdate
        union all
        select hostess from trip where date_trip between trunc(sysdate, 'year') and sysdate)
      group by (emp))
  where cnt = mcnt;
```

Use this query in `update` statement like here:

```
update employe set salary = salary * 1.05 
  where nb_emp in (
    select emp 
      from (
        select emp, count(1) cnt, max(count(1)) over () mcnt
          from (
            select driver as emp from trip where date_trip between trunc(sysdate, 'year') and sysdate
            union all
            select hostess from trip where date_trip between trunc(sysdate, 'year') and sysdate)
          group by (emp))
      where cnt = mcnt);
```

My test data:

```
create table employe(nb_emp, salary) as (
    select 'D1', 1000 from dual union all
    select 'D2', 1000 from dual union all
    select 'H1', 1000 from dual union all
    select 'H2', 1000 from dual union all
    select 'H3', 1000 from dual );

create table trip (id_trip, driver, hostess, date_trip) as (
    select 1, 'D1', 'H1', date '2019-01-01' from dual union all
    select 2, 'D1', 'H2', date '2019-01-01' from dual union all
    select 3, 'D1', 'H2', date '2019-01-02' from dual union all
    select 4, 'D2', 'H1', date '2019-01-02' from dual union all
    select 5, 'D2', 'H2', date '2019-01-03' from dual );
```

Driver D1 and hostess H2 made most trips (3) and their salaries were raised to `1050`.